# Oauth module for nginx using Python/C api

Tags: python, c, oauth, nginx

I'm writing a module to support 2-legged Oauth on nginx, and for that I'm using python for all the outh part.
I made it work when Oauth parameters are passed as request parameters, but I couldn't make it work yet when the oauth are passed via authorization headers. 
In fact my problem is that I'm using Python/C API and I can't pass the list of headers from C to Python because nginx C structures doesn't offer that ... I can't neither get the request body when it's a PUT or POST. 
Have any one faced this problem before, or is there any similar module that can help me...?
is there a way to get the http request as python object ?

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What a weird way... Why don't you use just FastCGI or uwsgi interface?

Comment: we have to use 2-legged Oauth, and we want to do that on nginx side, plus this nginx module make a lot of other security checking ... and as writing it with python is much easier and faster, we decided to use C/Python ...